# Aplicação Web Hibrida (MVC e Web API)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

No Visual Studio quando criamos um projeto web ele te da as opções para
marcar:

WebForms
MVC
Web API

Quando marco MVC + Web API os dois ficam no mesmo projeto.

Existem alguma vantagem/desempenho em usar MVC + Web API no mesmo
projeto ou é melhor separar o MVC do Web API em projetos diferentes
dentro da mesma Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não vejo problemas em trabalhar juntos, e isso não vai acarretar mau desempenho. Mas tudo em desenvolvimento de sistemas tem que ser analisado a fundo, se for um projeto MVC grande com uma diversidade de código, possa ser melhor dois projetos, mas, ai tem o inconveniente da publicação, teria que publicar separado em um domínio e um sub-domínio, para não haver aquela bagunça de aplicações (experiência própria).

Então, analise o ambiente, a quantidade de conexão, o trabalho e esforço que o servidor terá que fazer, se for um projeto até médio porte, pode fazer sem medo. Projetos maiores a divisão seria o mais ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Existe. A complexidade é menor, os *Scaffoldings* de um são, em grande parte, reaproveitados no outro e o contexto de dados pode ser o mesmo, evitando grandes retrabalhos.

A separação só deve ocorrer se um atrapalhar o funcionamento do outro, em casos como:

- Rotas
- Permissionamento
- Necessidades de isolamento específicas